# Zend .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, url-rewriting

My url is dynamic like
http://www.example.com/index/index/packagedetails/pkg_id/2VXcXACz9OILf_H2LxNIsblbUOqvVy4i3lOT2xZPLJo

OR

http://www.example.com/index/index/listing/tid/10

I want url display like http://www.example.com/package-details/pkg_id/2VXcXACz9OILf_H2LxNIsblbUOqvVy4i3lOT2xZPLJo

or

http://www.example.com/listing/tid/10 receptively. Thanx

Comment: If you display `http://www.example.com/package-details` how is your application going to know what the `pkg_id` is?

Comment: I have changed the url plz suggest.

Comment: And what is your current htaccess rules?

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

The following rules would rewrite `/index/index/*` URLs to their shortened versions and then resolve them back to the original ones (silently at the server side) after the redirection happens.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index/index(/listing/[^\s?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index/index/packagedetails/([^\s?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /package-details/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(listing/tid/.*)$ /index/index/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^package-details/(pkg_id/.*)$ /index/index/packagedetails/$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Need more info. Can you describe what's happening with those rules in place?

Comment: Nothing happens my application run as it was.

Comment: What url are you using? If you go to `http://www.example.com/listing/tid/10` do you not see the content of `http://www.example.com/index/index/listing/tid/10`?

Comment: My url is http://www.example.com/index/index/listing/tid/10 I want to change it like http://www.example.com/listing/tid/10

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error kindly support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70319/discussion-between-user1831355-and-ravi-thapliyal).

Comment: The rules I just added need `[R]` instead of `[L]`.